# Execute Filename.sql file in Java using MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I have a **`Filename.sql(Mysql Script)`** file which has multiple SQL Statements. I'm using MyBatis as persistence framework and MySQL as the database. I want to execute the `Filename.sql` file in a Java program.

NOTE: I don't want to execute the queries as separate SQL Statements.

This operation is equivalent to `source Filename.sql` in MySQL command prompt.

Comment: Experts, Please respond to this question.

Comment: This post http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802383/Run-SQL-Script-sql-containing-DDL-DML-SELECT-state and this http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-run-a-mysql-script-using-java/ might help. But please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

you can use org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner to do this:

```
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(dataSource.getConnection());
runner.setAutoCommit(true);
runner.setStopOnError(true);
runner.runScript(getResourceAsReader("Filename.sql"));
runner.closeConnection();
```

Comment: What about myBatis?

Comment: it is in the mybatis repo under the ibatis pkg path -- https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/a7e93b019e422fded9f01933ffae67d412490313/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/jdbc/ScriptRunner.java#L38

Answer (score 0):

```
private void runMysqlScript(String sqlScriptFilePath) {

    try {
        // Create MySQL Connection
        Class.forName(driverClassName);
        Connection connection = 
                DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword);
        // Initialize object for ScriptRunner
        ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(connection);
        // Give the input file to Reader
        Reader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sqlScriptFilePath));
        // Execute script
        runner.runScript(br);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about myBatis?

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can try to use something like liquibase or something similar, which brings you a healthy way of versioning your scripts. In this case you need to convert your .sql-script into the liquibase one. Then you can execute it with Maven plugin or just from Java. It allows you to control the state of your data.
Otherwise, for DML and DQL types of queries you can use the ScriptRunner approach.

Comment: What about myBatis?

Comment: myBatis has no functionality to work with .sql scripts.

Comment: I've found __ScriptRunner__ class in myBatis

Comment: You're right, agad. I haven't been known it before. Thanks! I found an example of ScriptRunner usage here: https://gist.github.com/rponte/665155